# Viewing image displayed on axes

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

(http://s1273.photobucket.com/user/Chethan_tv/media/CBIR_zpsb48bce14.jpg.html)

Above image is my final output, `open` push button is used to view image displayed on respective axes.
I've used following code for displaying

```
function open1_Callback(filename, hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to open1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
fid=fopen(filename);
ax = handles.(sprintf('axes%d', 6));
imshow(ax)
```

Where, 6 is axes number. But I'm getting error like 
`undefined variable handles`
To display image on axes I've used following code

```
function displayResults(filename,hObject, eventdata, handles)

% Open 'filename' file... for reading...
fid = fopen(filename);
for N=6:1:10
    imagename = fgetl(fid);
    if ~ischar(imagename), break, end       % Meaning: End of File...
    [x,map]=imread(imagename);
    rgb=ind2rgb(x,map);
    ax = handles.(sprintf('axes%d', N));
    image(rgb, 'Parent', ax);
    set(ax, 'Visible','off');
    %xlabel(imagename);  
end
guidata(hObject,handles)
```

filename is a text file.
HOW TO DISPLAY RESPECTIVE IMAGE USING PUSHBUTTON?

Comment: i just want to open the image that's get displayed on axes which is just above `open` button. So that viewer gets satisfied with large sized image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you messed the code generated by GUIDE.
Normally callback functione definition looks like this:

```
function SomeButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

But in your code you write

```
function open1_Callback(filename, hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

But guide still sends three arguments to the callback function (`hObject`, `eventdata`, and `handles`) in this specific order. So MatLab gets confused and throws an error.

You better put your filename into `handles` structure in `*_OpeningFcn` function and then use it from there in all calbacks.

At the end of your `*_OpeningFcn` you should add the following:

```
% Here you may put all the data you need in your GUI
% just be sure to keep all the fields in handles structure from overwriting
% Safe way is to add MyData field and add all the stuff to it
handles.MyData.ListFileName = 'FileName.txt';
% the next two lienes are generated by GUIDE

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Then in callback function of your button

```
function open1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to open1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% open the file
fid=fopen(handles.MyData.ListFileName);
% load lines from the file
% and do what is needed
for N=6:1:10
    imagename = fgetl(fid);
    if ~ischar(imagename), break, end       % Meaning: End of File...
    [x,map]=imread(imagename);
    rgb=ind2rgb(x,map);
    ax = handles.(sprintf('axes%d', N));
    image(rgb, 'Parent', ax);
    set(ax, 'Visible','off');
    %xlabel(imagename);  
end
% dont' forget to close the file
fclose(fid);
% If your callback function modifies data in handles.MyData structure
% you MUST update it back otherwise subsequent call-backs will not see it
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

And yes, all the files you open with `fopen` function should be closed with `fclose`. You will learn it hard way when you'll not be able to update your file in your favorite editor because another programs is using it.

See also ([Making universal variables in MATLAB GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470517/making-universal-variables-in-matlab-gui/))

**UPDATE to reflect discussion in comments:**

To achieve the behavior you want I'd do the following:

At the end of your `*_OpeningFcn` add the following:

```
% Here you may put all the data you need in your GUI
% just be sure to keep all the fields in handles structure from overwriting
% Safe way is to add MyData field and add all the stuff to it
handles.MyData.ListFileName = 'FileName.txt';
handles.MyData.FileNames = {}; % here we store all the image names
handles.MyData.Images    = {}; % here we store all images
% Now we parse data from the file
fid=fopen(handles.MyData.ListFileName);
for N=6:1:10
    imagename = fgetl(fid);
    if ~ischar(imagename), break, end       % Meaning: End of File...
    [x,map]=imread(imagename);
    rgb=ind2rgb(x,map);
    ax = handles.(sprintf('axes%d', N));
    image(rgb, 'Parent', ax);
    set(ax, 'Visible','off');
    %xlabel(imagename);

    % store file name and image itself for later use
    handles.MyData.Images{N} = rgb;
    handles.MyData.FileNames{N} = imagename;

    % we have buttons like open1 open2 open3 etc...
    % add some info to the open buttons
    % so they will be aware which image they display
    btn = handles.(sprintf('open%d', N));
    set(btn, 'UserData',N);
end
% dont' forget to close the file
fclose(fid);
% the next two lienes are generated by GUIDE

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Then in callback function for your open button do the following

```
function open1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to open1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

N   = get(hObject,'UserData');
rgb = handles.MyData.Images{N};
ax  = handles.(sprintf('axes%d', N));
% create figure in 'modal' mode, so user have to close it to continue
figure('WindowStyle','modal', 'Name',handles.MyData.FileNames{N} );
% show image
image(rgb, 'Parent', ax);
set(ax, 'Visible','off');
% If your callback function modifies data in handles.MyData structure
% you MUST update it back otherwise subsequent call-backs will not see it
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Basically, this callback is universal: it should work without modifications for all your open buttons. You may even change callback function of `open2`, `open3` ... buttons in GUIDE to `open1_Callback`.

Comment: You have several `axes`/`open` button pairs: `axes` display an image, `open` buttons should display the corresponding image in bigger size. Is it correct?

Comment: This means you don't have `open6` button

Comment: Are you sure you have enough images listed in your data file?

Comment: This means that N is greater than number of elements in handles.MyData.Images

Comment: N is 6 to 10 i.e., 5. Then according to above code, `handles.MyData.Images` also gets 5 images. then which part of code is wrong? AND please delete your previous comments for further conversation