# Retaining a Plot on a Image drawn using impoint function

Tags: image, matlab, plot, matlab-guide, axes

I have a number of images to be marked with certain fixed number of points. (object tracking)
I am using `impoint` to make the points on the image and then plot to connect them to each other in a logical way. So far so good. Next, I hit next (on my MATLAB GUI developed using GUIDE) and the new image loads in the axis and the information is lost (the point).

- How can I retain the plotted `impoint` for my next image?
- How can I make sure that when I move the `impoint`, the plotted lines also move?

What I still have to work around is:

That I am already using the `addNewPositionCallback` for the updation of the position of the point. This callback when written: `addNewPositionCallback(H, @fnc);` it issues a function call something like `fnc(pos)`

> My problem is that this call back does not provide a handle.

Hence without the handles information I can not address the right element in the Code. As of now I have implemented it so, that I have written 18 One-liner functions for the fixed number of 18 points that I need to mark on the image. these functions call the same function `updatestructure(position, 'point_name', handles)` which is called right after the creation of impoints to plot the link between them on the image. But here too I have no information on handles. Here is what I tried:

```
pointname = impoint(gca,[]);
setcolor(h,'y');
position = getPosition(h);
updatestructure(position, 'pointname', handles);
addNewPositionCallback(h, @movepointname)
```

So when update structure is called the plot works fine. I can see what I want. But when I move the point function `movepointname()` is called and thats when problem starts.

```
function movepointname (smart_pos)
updateStruct (smart_pos, 'pointname');
end
```

This surely generated an error as the handles information was not transferred. I tried `vargin` to define what it should do when less argument call is set. In that I would still need handles from somewhere.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use handles when you display and update your images and plots.

For example, when you display image first time (on any axes):

```
 hImg = image(ImageMatrix);
```

The to update it do not issue `image` or `imagesc` or other function,
but update it directly instead:

```
set(hImg, 'CData',NewImageMatrix');
```

In this case everything else on your axes will remain intact.

You can do the same trick with your points. First time you plot like this:

```
hPlot = plot( PointsX, PointsY, '*-' ); % to plot * connected with line
```

Then you do

```
set(hPlot, 'XData',NewPointsX, 'YData',NewPointsY );
```

Note that number of actual points when you update your plot does not need to be the same: you can first plot 3 points and then update the plot handle to show 33 points.

Also in the initialization function of your GUI you can create empty plot with

```
hPlot = plot( [], [], '*-' );
```

to plot actually nothing, but the handle will be available for further updates.
Same thing should work with images as well, but you may have issues with axes limits update when you update the image to another one with different number of rows/columns. To solve this you can update the image like this:

```
set(hImg, 'CData',NewImageMatrix', 'XData',1:size(NewImageMatrix,2), 'YData',1:size(NewImageMatrix,1) );
```

**EDIT**: Ok, above will solve your first problem.
To update your lines when you move `impoint`, you have to look for the `impoint` reference and more specifically the `addNewPositionCallback` function.
Then you have to define call-back function that updates lines (it could be even a normal plot handle like the `hPlot` above) with new coordinates.

Comment: That you for your detailed response. i could not add more information here because of character limit. have added the information in the question decription to exaplin the problem in more detail.

Comment: I remember some time ago I faced similar issue with `imrect` rectangles, because they also do not expose their handles in callbacks. See here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/282342 hope it helps somehow

Comment: I guess I found the solution. Will post complete solution in detail once it works. Still working on it. back after a short holiday, little rusty.

Comment: This somehow does not work. I get a error saying: `??? Reference to non-existent field 'hPlot'.` when I try to set the values using `set(handles.hPlot, 'XData', x, 'YData', y,'Color','w','LineWidth',1);`. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Seems that there is no `hPlot` in the `handles` structure. Make sure you store the modified `handles` structure at the end of each callback function that modified it with `guidata(hObject, handles);`.

Comment: :I did succeed to make the changes without any error.but I do not see any plot as now.my code:
`function [handles] = drawplot(p,I,b,handles)
global Temp_Struct
persistent start
persistent hPlot
if (nargin < 2) set(hPlot, 'XData',[],'YData',[]); %to delete
    else % to plot
 start.(p).x = Temp_Struct.(I).(p).x;
 start.(p).y = Temp_Struct.(I).(p).y;
 next_x = Temp_Struct.(I).(b).x;
 next_y = Temp_Struct.(I).(b).y;
 x = [start.(p).x; next_x];
 y = [start.(p).y; next_y];
 hold (handles.Image_axis, 'on');
 set(hPlot, 'XData', x, 'YData', y, 'Color', 'w', 'LineWidth', 1);
end`

Comment: Your code looks OK to me, but its hard to say why you do not see the plot without seeing the rest (just in case, are you sure you need white plot?). Personally, I do not like global variables and write GUI code like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470517/making-universal-variables-in-matlab-gui/16475260#16475260

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the figure to draw over the image. To do this use the HOLD function.

```
hold(AXIS_HANDLE, 'on')
```

where AXIS_HANDLE is the axes handle. You need to do this prior to trying to plot anything else on the figure.

If you only have set of axes you can just call

```
hold on
```

after you create the axes.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer to the second part of my question was found on the link: [Mathworks forum. old question](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/282342)

The trick to pass other variables or call the function in the `addNewPositionCallback` is as below:

```
addNewPositionCallback(Point_handle,@(p)movepointname(p,'point_Name',handles));
```

This statement above passes the handles that  I wanted as per my original question and also allows me to pass some additional variables. The `(p)` is for the default callback of this function as `movepointname(p);` is for the current position of the point.

Hope it helps.